# using sort and uniq -c in awk from second line of data

Tags: sorting, awk, uniq

There are many questions similar to this, but they all (that I have seen) are interested in sorting and counting repeated strings from the first line of data. In my case I need to leave the first line intact and on top, while calling `sort | uniq -c` for all the following lines. I have gotten to the sorting part, the only part I'm stuck with is the `uniq -c` one. I've tried pipes, calling `system("uniq -c")`, other combinations of `system(...)`, but nothing seems to work. My current line of commands looks like this, but it only gets to the sorting part:

`myProgram input_file other_input_file | awk 'NR<2{print $0;next}{print $0 | "sort"}'`

and from this I get:

```
Id: revision_data  #this needs to stay on top
0
0
10.1007/S00253-012-4050-Z
10.1007/S00775-006-0142-5
10.1021/ACS.BIOCHEM.5B00958
10.1021/BI020286F
10.1038/35422
10.1093/NAR/28.8.1743
10.1093/NAR/GKN245
10.7554/ELIFE.00813
```

while what I need is this:

```
Id: revision_data
   2 0
   1 10.1007/S00253-012-4050-Z
   1 10.1007/S00775-006-0142-5
   1 10.1021/ACS.BIOCHEM.5B00958
   1 10.1021/BI020286F
   1 10.1093/NAR/28.8.1743
   1 10.1093/NAR/GKN245
   1 10.7554/ELIFE.00813
```

how could I insert `uniq -c` to my commands to get the output that I need?

Comment: Why is `10.1038/35422` not in output?

Comment: probably missed it not on purpose. sorry!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So just save the first line, output it and then continue with your script.

```
{
   IFS= read -r firstline
   printf "%s\n" "$firstline"
   sort | uniq -c
} < input_file
```

Comment: how do you suggest putting it in a one-liner pipe? since myProgram outputs one line at a time and only after it's done, I need the sorting to happen. with awk or any other command?

Comment: `blablacommand1 | { IFS= read -r firstline; printf "%s\n" "$firstline"; sort | uniq -c; } | blablacommand2`

Comment: thanks! i tried this before commenting to your answer, but it seems I didn't leave spaces before and after `{`

Answer (score 2):

You may use this `gnu awk`:

```
awk 'NR == 1 { print; next } { ++freq[$0] } END {
     PROCINFO["sorted_in"] = "@ind_str_asc"; for (i in freq) print freq[i], i }' file
```

```
Id: revision_data
2 0
1 10.1007/S00253-012-4050-Z
1 10.1007/S00775-006-0142-5
1 10.1021/ACS.BIOCHEM.5B00958
1 10.1021/BI020286F
1 10.1038/35422
1 10.1093/NAR/28.8.1743
1 10.1093/NAR/GKN245
1 10.7554/ELIFE.00813
```

Answer (score 1):

You could concatenate the first line of the file with your command applied to the other lines.

For example:

> cat <(head -n1 filename) <(sort <(tail -n+2 filename) | uniq -c)

This applies a `sort | uniq -c` to all lines starting with the second (via the `tail -n+2`).  That's concatenated to the first line (via `head -n1`) using `cat`.